Struggling to write data with multiple fields in influxDB
So I'm pretty new to influxDB. I'm trying to create a new measurement (akin to SQL tables according to the doc), with three fields, two tags and the timestamp.
The writing of the data goes fine, but when I try to visualize it through the InfluxDBExplorer app, the data appears to be splitted into multiple entries; the _field value being the names of the fields I wanted to have, and the _value field being the actual individual values of the corresponding fields.
Here's my Python snippet:
points = []
    for row in batch:
    point = Point("PERF").tag('ID',int(row[0]))\
                             .tag('service','LPV200')\
                             .time('2024-03-04')\
                             .field('avail',float(row[8]))\
                             .field('lon',float(row[1]))\
                             .field('lat',float(row[2]))
    points.append(point)
write_api.write(bucket, org,points)

The rows are coming from a txt file that I'm reading through the script.
The table looks like this when consulted through the browser:
Screenshot of the influx table view
I'm not sure if the issue if the actual writing of my points or if the visualisation tool is just not displaying the data like it's stored.
